# CUPS - reset preset menu to "default settings" after printing

Tags: xfce, cups, xubuntu

Once in a while I'm choosing duplex printing or landscape orientation when printing.
These choices are stored, so for the next print job I often end up with incorrect prints having to be re-printed.
I want this to be reset to my default settings after every print job.

I've already set the default settings at http://localhost:631/printers/.

A search revealed that there's a [dedicated GUI option in MacOS](https://www.jamf.com/jamf-nation/discussions/32825/reset-preset-menu-to-default-settings-after-printing-command-line-or-plist-setting) for that specific purpose, yet I haven't discovered such a setting in XFCE.

The MacOS config file `~/Library/Preferences/org.cups.PrintingPrefs.plist` is mentioned with a setting `com.apple.print.preset.defaultToStandardPreset`, but I wasn't able to find such an existing config file and I'm not sure in which path I should create it in Linux.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Define multiple printers (print queues) that have the desired characteristics, but access the same physical printer. Send your prints to the print queue with the desired characteristics. Use the `cupsenable` and `cupsdisable` commands to activate 1 queue at a time. Read `man -k cups`.

Comment: @waltinator That's certainly a good workaround. I'd still prefer some setting similar to defaultToStandardPreset in the MacOS version of CUPS though, but it seems to be absent in the Linux version of CUPS.